# Do Standard Library (STL) Containers support a form of nothrow allocation?

Tags: c++, stl, standard-library

The `new` operator (or for PODs, malloc/calloc) support a simple and efficient form of failing when allocating large chunks of memory.

Say we have this:

```
const size_t sz = GetPotentiallyLargeBufferSize(); // 1M - 1000M
T* p = new (nothrow) T[sz];
if(!p) {
  return sorry_not_enough_mem_would_you_like_to_try_again;
}
...
```

Is there any such construct for the std::containers, or will I always have to handle an (expected!!) exception with `std::vector` and friends?

---

Would there maybe be a way to write a custom allocator that preallocates the memory and then pass this custom allocator to the vector, so that as long as the vector does not ask for more memory than you put into the allocator beforehand, it will not fail?

---

*Afterthought*: What really would be needed were a member function `bool std::vector::reserve(std::nothrow) {...}` in addition to the normal reserve function. But since that would only make sense if allocators were extended too to allow for nothrow allocation, it just won't happen. Seems (nothrow) new is good for something after all :-)

---

Edit: As to *why* I'm even asking this:

I thought of this question while debugging (1st chance / 2nd chance exception handling of the debugger): If I've set my debugger to 1st-chance catch any bad_alloc because I'm testing for low-memory conditions, it would be annoying if it also caught those bad_alloc exceptions that are already well-expected and handled in the code. It wasn't/isn't a really big problem but it just occurred to me that the sermon goes that exceptions are for exceptional circumstances, and something I already expect to happen every odd call in the code is not exceptional.

If `new (nothrow)` has it's legitimate uses, the a vector-nothrow-reserve also would have.

Comment: It's not such a big deal to write a `try...catch` construct. If you have lots of them, you could write a single wrapper function `template<typename T> T* MyAlloc (size_t)`, with the exception handling inside.

Comment: it sometimes is such a big deal.

Comment: even when you're allocating a gigabyte and approaching OOM?  I doubt it.

Comment: @Eamon : The question is about `exception`, not failure. If 1G is requested, it will very likely *fail*, but it will *not* throw an *exception* with `(nothrow)`.

Comment: @Martin: Can you explain why you don't want any exceptions to be thrown? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @TonyK: You're quite right for asking why I would want this. I intentionally left this out of the question, because then I'd get answers questioning my motives instead of something focusing on the actual question. :-)  (I'll add an edit explaining some more.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default, the standard STL container classes use the `std::allocator` class under the hood to do their allocation, which is why they can throw `std::bad_alloc` if there's no memory available.  Interestingly, the C++ ISO specification on allocators states that the return value of any allocator type *must* be a pointer to a block of memory capable of holding some number of elements, which automatically precludes you from building a custom allocator that could potentially use the `nothrow` version of `new` to have these sorts of silent allocation failures.  You could, however, build a custom allocator that terminated the program if no memory was available, since then it's vacuously true that the returned memory is valid when no memory is left. :-)

In short, the standard containers throw exceptions by default, and any way you might try to customize them with a custom allocator to prevent exceptions from being thrown won't conform to the spec.

Comment: Most of the methods calling allocator don't have any other way to report error than via exception anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Too often we hear "I don't want to use exceptions because they are inefficient".

Unless you are referring to an "embedded" environment where you want all runtime type information switched off, you should not be worrying too much about inefficiency of exceptions if they are being thrown in an appropriate way. Running out of memory is one of these appropriate ways.

Part of the contract of vector is that it will throw if it cannot allocate. If you write a custom allocator that returned NULL instead that would be worse, as it would cause undefined behaviour.

If you have to then use an allocator that will first attempt a failed-allocation callback if one is available, and only then if you still cannot allocate to throw, but still you have to end up with an exception.

Can I give you a hint though: if you really are allocating such large amounts of data then vector is probably the wrong class to use and you should use std::deque instead. Why? Because deque does not require a contiguous block of memory but is still constant time lookup. And the advantages are two-fold:

1. - Allocations will fail less frequently. Because you do not need a contiguous block so you may well have the memory available albeit not in a single block.
2. - There is no reallocation, just more allocations. Reallocations are expensive as it requires all your objects to be moved. When you are in high-volume mode that can be a very timely operation.

When I worked on such a system in the past we found we could actually stored over 4 times as much data using deque as we could using vector because of the reason 1 above, and it was faster because of the reason 2.

Something else we did was allocate a 2MB spare buffer and when we caught a bad_alloc we freed the buffer and then threw anyway to show we had reached capacity. But with 2MB spare now we at least knew we had the memory to perform small operations to move the data from memory to temporary disk storage.

Thus we could catch the bad_alloc sometimes and take an appropriate action retaining a consistent state, which is the purpose of exceptions rather than assuming that running out of memory is always fatal and should never do anything other than terminate the program (or even worse, invoke undefined behaviour).

Comment: Thanks about the tip regarding `deque` -- interesting observation, might be worth a try. (Though, as my original code sugessts, if someone's requiring a >500MB buffer, it is pretty likely to fail most of the time no matter how you fragment it.)

Comment: @Martin: why is a 500MG `deque` likely to fail? The point of `deque` is that it isn't a single buffer, it's many allocations. If you're running on an even vaguely modern PC, for example, then 500MB in small chunks should be allocated comfortably. More than about 3 such allocations simultaneously might start to get tricky on a 32 bit OS/process.

Comment: @Steve - Yes, 32bit process. It's not the physical RAM running out, but the address space of the process is getting "full". One problem I'd see with a `deque` is that you really can't be too sure how it's going to split up your buffer. So you might have situations where it's working great and other (fragmentation) scenarios where it's not working at all. Might be an interesting question in itself.

Comment: @Martin: it's implementation-dependent, but implementations of `deque` I've seen use quite small chunks, under 1kb. It should be able to use pretty much any available address space.

Comment: Exception problem is IMO not related with inefficiency: The problem is that  under the pressure of the project and to avoid reading documentation all the time, the first thing that fall from the normal programmer code is exception management. So your application work 100% under development and crash randomly at the client. IMO an error mechanism shall be as mandatory as a parameter: so the programmer is aware and will manage it. So I use nothrow, because it is simpler to check a pointer "if(!ptr)" than writing a full try-catch block.

Answer (score 3):

Standard containers use exceptions for this, you can't get around it other than attempting the allocation only once you know it will succeed. You can't do that portably, because the implementation will typically over-allocate by an unspecified amount. If you have to disable exceptions in the compiler then you're limited in what you can do with containers.

Regarding "simple and efficient", I think that the `std` containers are reasonably simple and reasonably efficient:

```
T* p = new (nothrow) T[sz];
if(!p) {
    return sorry_not_enough_mem_would_you_like_to_try_again;
}
... more code that doesn't throw ...
delete[] p;

try {
    std::vector<T> p(sz);
    ... more code that doesn't throw ...
} catch (std::bad_alloc) {
    return sorry_not_enough_mem_would_you_like_to_try_again;
}
```

It's the same number of lines of code. If it presents an efficiency problem in the failure case then your program must be failing hundreds of thousands of times per second, in which case I slightly question the program design. I also wonder under what circumstances the cost of throwing and catching an exception is significant compared with the cost of the system call that `new` probably makes to establish that it can't satisfy the request.

But even better, how about writing your APIs to use exceptions too:

```
std::vector<T> p(sz);
... more code that doesn't throw ...
```

Four lines shorter than your original code, and the caller who currently has to handle "sorry_not_enough_mem_would_you_like_to_try_again" can instead handle the exception. If this error code is passed up through several layers of callers, you might save four lines at each level. C++ has exceptions, and for almost all purposes you may as well accept this and write code accordingly.

Regarding "(expected!!)" - sometimes you know how to handle an error condition. The thing to do in that case is to catch the exception. It's how exceptions are supposed to work. If the code that throws the exception somehow knew that there was no point anyone ever catching it, then it could terminate the program instead.

Comment: Regarding your proposition to just have the API propagate the exception: I think propagating bad_alloc when you already know which allocation of critical size might fail is a pretty bad idea. Whatever code is going to catch it would be none the wiser where or which allocation failed, and if you already know that you're doing critical size allocations then I think it's really better to catch bad_alloc and rethrow something with more information / something that can be caught+handled in a more specific way.

Comment: @Martin: well, you know your specific use case and I don't. If the code needs the memory, then I don't see how its need for 1GB of memory is substantially different from code that needs 1 byte of (dynamically allocated) memory. Normally "try again" is not a good response to out-of-memory, but if in your specific case there are some allocations for which just trying again might work, and others for which it won't, then by all means distinguish between the two.