# With "-fno-exceptions", what happens with "new T"?

Tags: c++, exception

I was wondering, will `new T` still throw `bad_alloc` if I compile my program using the `-fno-exceptions` option to disable exception handling?

Or will the compiler (GCC and clang support that option) implicitly transform the use of `new T` to `new (nothrow) T`?

Comment: Interesting question. But, why do you want to disable it?

Comment: I don't want to disable it :)

Comment: Just curious, are you dealing with code that routinely throws `bad_alloc`?

Comment: I'm not dealing with any code. I'm only dealing with thoughts in the air.

Comment: Since the C++ Standard does not consider this case, and since many Standard Library implementations assume (because of the Standard) that allocators always return a valid block of memory (it's guaranteed), you would have to forgo the Standard Library in such a program... and thus provide your own `new` and `delete`, I surmise.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I can't give a definitive answer to all the perks around -fno-exceptions, just the observations on a 32 bit linux machine, gcc 4.5.1 - bad_alloc is thrown with and without `-fno-exceptions`

```
[21:38:35 1 ~/tmp] $ cat bad_alloc.cpp

int main()
{
    char* c = new char[4000000000U];
}
[21:38:58 1 ~/tmp] $ g++ bad_alloc.cpp
[21:39:06 1 ~/tmp] $ ./a.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
[21:39:07 1 ~/tmp] $ g++ -fno-exceptions bad_alloc.cpp
[21:39:16 1 ~/tmp] $ ./a.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

Comment: wouldn't you need to rebuild the C++ Standard library with `-fno-exceptions` in order to get the fully desired result?

Comment: Clang stops code with throw from compiling when exceptions are disabled, does GCC have similar behaviour?

Answer (score 76):

The way I understand it, `operator new` is defined by libstdc++. If you now compile your own code with `-fno-exceptions`, you cannot catch any exceptions, but you will still be linking against the normal version of libstdc++, which does throw an exception.

So yes, `new T` will throw an exception, even with `-fno-exception`.

However, if you compiled libstdc++ with `-fno-exception` as well, things become different. Now, `new T` cannot throw an exception but, if I read [the libstdc++ manual right](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html#intro.using.exception.no) it will call `abort()` instead.

It seems that, if you want your `new T` to return NULL on failure, the only way is to explicitely specify `nothrow`...

Comment: @nos This is a good contrast to the accepted answer, and really shows, in more detail, what is going on with the case of `cat bad_alloc.cpp`, above.

Answer (score 10):

It's not a definitive answer, but the [GCC Manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html) (see the section "Doing Without") has this:

> Before detailing the library support
>   for `-fno-exceptions`, first a passing
>   note on the things lost when this flag
>   is used: it will break exceptions
>   trying to pass through code compiled
>   with `-fno-exceptions` whether or not
>   that code has any try or catch
>   constructs. If you might have some
>   code that throws, you shouldn't use
>   `-fno-exceptions`.

The way I read that, you might have to explicitly ask for the nothrow version of `new` to be completely safe.

Comment: Which will require a custom libstdcxx dynamic library. And such library can't be spec compliant for reasons explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826838/do-standard-library-stl-containers-support-a-form-of-nothrow-allocation

Answer (score 0):

In many exception-handling systems, if routine "foo" calls "bar", which in turn calls "moo", and "moo" throws an exception, the only way that exception can cleanly make it back to "foo" is if "bar" has code to handle the exception.  Even if "bar" is going to let the exception propagate uncaught, it will generally have to ensure that its local variables get properly destroyed before execution is allowed to leave scope.  This will require adding extra code to "bar"; in most systems, some of that code will have to execute even if no exception is thrown.

BTW, on some ARM processors like the Cortex M3, or like the Arm7 running in ARM mode, if the caller is also going to be running in ARM mode, one could allow for exceptions without any execution-time cost by having a "normal" subroutine return go to LR+4 (four bytes beyond the normal return address) and have an exceptional exit go to LR (which would then be a 4-byte branch instruction).  Such behavior would be contrary to normal practice on the ARM, though, and such a design would not port nicely to the Cortex M0.

Comment: So, given that information, does GCC convert `new` to `new (nothrow)`? ;-p