# NULL in instantiation

Tags: c++, null

When writing C++, let's assume the following line of code:

```
Object* obj = new Object();
```

If this line both compiles and does not cause exceptions or any other visible
runtime problems, can obj be NULL right after this line was executed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, `obj` cannot be `NULL`.

If `new` fails, it will throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception. If no exception was thrown, `obj` is guaranteed to point to a fully initialized instance of `Object`.

There is a variant of `new` that doesn't throw an exception

```
Object *obj = new(nothrow) Object();
```

In this case, `obj` will be `NULL` if `new` fails, and the `std::bad_alloc` exception will not be thrown (though `Object`'s constructor can obviously still throw exceptions).

On some older compilers, `new` might not throw an exception and rather return `NULL` instead, but this is not standards-compliant behaviour.

If you've overloaded `operator new`, it might behave differently depending on your implementation.

Comment: Or unless you've done something like `#define new new(nothrow)` perhaps? ;)

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: That is undefined behaviour

Comment: What happens when you compile without exceptions? Will it use the nothrow version automatically?

Comment: @Tamás: See @littleadv's answer with the link.

Answer (score 5):

No, your exact line cannot behave like that. `obj` will always point to valid memory if no exceptions are thrown. The following line, though, will return `0` if the memory could not be allocated:

```
Object* obj = new (std::nothrow) Object();
```

Answer (score 3):

`new` throws `std::bad_alloc` is allocation was not sucessful. So you should catch that exception.
You should use nothrow new if you want to be checking for `NULL` after `new.`

Answer (score 2):

No, unless you disabled exceptions or overloaded `std::new` to do something other than the standard one (which throws `std::bad_alloc` on failure).

(I'm not sure how `std::new` behaves when exceptions are disabled, but a discussion on this is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049563/with-fno-exceptions-what-happens-with-new-t)...)

Comment: The standard does not define how new behaves when exceptions are disabled, because the standard does not define a world where exceptions can be disabled. It's up to each individual compiler implementation.