# Are all functions "noexcept" if exceptions are disabled?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, language-lawyer

If you turn off exceptions by compiling with `-fno-exceptions` are all functions considered noexcept for example by `std::move_if_noexcept` or do you still have to declare functions noexcept for that reason?

Comment: Lots of functions [may still throw exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049563/with-fno-exceptions-what-happens-with-new-t) despite compiling with `-fno-exceptions`

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html doesn't say much about it, I'm not sure if that's the definitive reference though.

Comment: Someone has [asked](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.devel/30992) pretty much the same question on the clang mailing list, and the answer given is *compiling with `-fno-exceptions` is not the same as specifying `noexcept` for all functions*.

Comment: `-f` options affect code generation, not types.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `-fno-exceptions` will prevent you from throwing exceptions, but it can not prevent exceptions being thrown from libraries.

For example, next example will terminate because of not caught exception :

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6};

    return v.at(55);
}
```

But next example will not compile, because of `-fno-exceptions` option :

```
int main()
{
    throw 22;
}
```

It fails with :

```
g++   -std=c++11 -g  -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions ./garbage.cpp 
./garbage.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./garbage.cpp:4:8: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
  throw 22;
```

From [this article, Doing without chapter](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html) :

> User code that uses C++ keywords like throw, try, and catch will
>   produce errors even if the user code has included libstdc++ headers
>   and is using constructs like basic_iostream.

---

On the other hand, `noexcept` marks the method as a method that doesn't throw exceptions. Any thrown exception will call `std::terminate` (see [except.terminate]/2 in c++ standard).

Next example :

```
struct A
{
    void foo() noexcept
    {
        throw 33;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    try
    {
        a.foo();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }
}
```

terminates with :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

To conclude : the behavior is quite different when you use `-fno-exceptions` and when you mark the function as `noexcept`.

---

> Although I compile my whole project with -fno-exceptions(for other reasons) I still have to declare move constructors an move assigment operators noexcept to enable move semantic for std::move_if_noexcept?

When you use that option, the functions are not automatically marked as noexcept. You have to do it manually. The compiler is not allowed to do such modifications.

If such modification would be allowed, then [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept) would produce different outputs.

Comment: I know, that the behavior is quite different. My Question ist: Although I compile my whole project with `-fno-exceptions`(for other reasons) I still have to declare move constructors an move assigment operators noexcept to enable move semantic for std::move_if_noexcept?

Comment: @TNA Ok, so I misunderstood the point. Hopefully edit corrected it

Comment: @BЈовић Can you please add a reliable source for your claim that adding `-fno-exceptions` to the compiler options is not enough to trigger the same performance optimizations as manually marking all functions `noexcept`? Right now your supporting arguments are a bit vague and seem to only address your earlier (wrong) understanding of the question.

Comment: Related question: Will `-fno-exceptions` compiler option trigger the same performance benefits as marking a function `noexcept` in this case: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AG_63_edgUg ?

Comment: Update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787766/when-should-i-really-use-noexcept#comment121480642_67134262 I tested how GCC and clang behave and that  seems to support your statement.