# GDB cannot load binary to target with C and C++ mixing program using std::

Tags: c++, c, gdb, std, riscv

I'm trying to port a C++ source into my C-based project (main function in C) for my target which is based on risc-v cpu. The program could be compiled without any problems, but I couldn't load the binary to the target in some cases.

In my code, there are 3 classes **Switch, Member and Adapter**. The class Adapter inherits the class Member in which there are the uses of **std::vector**.

I've tried 4 cases like following:

**Case 1:**

In the program, I created an object of the class **Switch**. The code was compiled without error, but I couldn't load the binary to the target. I got the errors related to GDB like in 2 below photos:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i42lr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZldQv.png)

In addition, I got the symbols related to exceptions handling and std:: :

***<__cxa_allocate_exception>***

***<__cxa_throw>***

***<std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc()>***

***<std::bad_exception::~bad_exception()>***

***...***

**Case 2:**

In this case, I created an object of the class **Switch** while overriding the **new** and **delete** operators. The binary could be loaded to the target.

Compared to the case 1, there wasn't any exceptions handling symbol, and the only one related to std:: was **std::type_info**.

**Case 3:**

This time, in the program I created an object of class **Switch** and an object of class **Adapter**. The new and delete operators were always overridden. I got the same errors with the case 1.

In the symbols list, I found again a lot of exceptions handling and std:: symbols.

**Case 4:**

For this case, I created an object of class **Switch** and used **std::vector<>** in my code. I got the same errors with the case 1.

And of course, lots of exceptions handling and std:: symbols were in the symbol list.

The results obtained can show that my problem is due to **std::**, I've already tried **--fno-exceptions -nostdlib -std=gnu++0x** when linking the objects, but still can't resolve the issue.

**PS:** I used **riscv32-elf-** (nds32le-elf-mculib-v5f) toolchain and GDB integrated in **AndeSight**.

Have you guys ever had the same problem with mine?

Do you have any advises when mixing C and C++ in terms of compilation and linkage?

Any repose would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using C++ on embedded platforms can be troublesome, especially when setting up the project. I don’t know your exact platform, but for sure to use -fnoexceptions the whole stdlib has to be recompiled with it. You can have a look at [this](https://github.com/DISTORTEC/distortos) project to see how to use C++ in embedded context (on ARM though).

Comment: You mean that the stdlib has to be recompiled before the final linkage?

Comment: please show a [mre] and don't post images of text, post the text directly

Comment: @NguyênPhạmNgọcKhôi see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6049745/4885321
Maybe this can be circumvented by using custom allocators, I don't know right off the bat.

Comment: You're missing the C++ language runtime (not exactly the same thing as the C++ standard library). You can probably avoid needing it by rebuilding your C++ standard library in freestanding (non-hosted) mode and disabling RTTI and exceptions in your entire stack, but what that will mean and how it will act is completely unspecified. Other than that is the rule is you have use a C++ linker if you use any C++ because the language runtimes and startups are different.